# Sort a list item up or down

Tags: javascript, html, sorting, listitem

A very simple example of what i am trying to do below. Link/button on left to move item up, link/button on right to move the item down.  But it is not working, and i am getting an error:

> Object doesnt support this property or method

at this line:

```
items[counter-1] = curr;// move
previous item, to current
```

Example Image:

[image]

Here is my code:

```js
function MoveItem(id, direction) {
  var ul = document.getElementById('GroupBy');
  var items = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');

  var counter = 0;
  var previousItem = null;
  var moveNextItemUp = false;

  for (var item in items) {

    //if current item, is the one to be moved
    if (item == id) {
      if (direction == 1) { // item move down
        moveNextItemUp = true;
      } else if ((direction == -1) || (moveNextItemUp == true)) { // item move up
        var curr = items[counter];
        var prev = items[counter - 1];

        items[counter - 1] = curr; // move previous item, to current
        items[counter] = prev; //move current item, to previous

        break;
      }
    }

    previousItem = item;
    counter = counter + 1;
  }

}
```

```html
<ul id="GroupBy">
  <li id="One">
    one<a href="#" onclick="MoveItem('One', 1)"> V </a>
  </li>
  <li id="Two">
    <a href="#" onclick="MoveItem('Two', -1)"> ^ </a>two<a href="#" onclick="MoveItem('Two', 1)"> V </a>
  </li>
  <li id="Three">
    <a href="#" onclick="MoveItem('Three', -1)"> ^ </a>three<a href="#" onclick="MoveItem('Three', 1)"> V </a>
  </li>
  <li id="Four">
    <a href="#" onclick="MoveItem('Four', -1)"> ^ </a>four
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using a `for-in` statement, which means that you don't have any guarantee of the numeric order you may expect.

Use a `for` statement instead:

```
for (var i = 0, len = items.length; i < len; i++) {
```

Also, keep in mind that `items` is a "live list", so changes you make in the DOM are reflected in the list, and the list itself is immutable since it isn't an Array.

If you want to shift an element back one index, use `insertBefore`.

Something like this:

```
items[i].parentNode.insertBefore( items[i],items[i-1] );
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/d25a3/

```
function MoveItem(id, direction) {
    var ul = document.getElementById('GroupBy');
    var items = ul.getElementsByTagName('li');

    var counter = 0;
    var previousItem = null;
    var moveNextItemUp = false;

    for (var i = 0, len = items.length; i < len; i++) {
        var item = items[i];

        if (item.id == id) {
            if (direction == 1) { 
                moveNextItemUp = true;
            } else if ((direction == -1) || (moveNextItemUp == true)) {

                item.parentNode.insertBefore( item,items[i-1] );
                break;
            }
        }
        previousItem = item;
        counter = counter + 1;
    }
}
```

Also, not sure what the full intent of the code is, but it would seem that you could simplify something like this:

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/d25a3/1/

```
   <!-- pass the parent node of the item clicked as the first argument -->

<li id="Two">
    <a href="#" onclick="MoveItem(this.parentNode, -1)"> ^ </a>two<a href="#" onclick="MoveItem('Two', 1)"> V </a>
</li>
```

And get rid of the loop entirely:

```
function MoveItem(item, direction) {

    var counter = 0;
    var previousItem = null;
    var moveNextItemUp = false;

    if (direction == 1) {
        moveNextItemUp = true;
    } else if ((direction == -1) || (moveNextItemUp == true)) {

           // get the previous <li> element
        var prev = item.previousSibling
        while( prev && prev.nodeType != 1 && (prev = prev.previousSibling));

        item.parentNode.insertBefore(item, prev);
    }
    previousItem = item;
    counter = counter + 1;
}
```

Comment: I have commented out my for-in loop, and put in your for loop, as well as the items[i].parentNode line of code (inside the loop).   however, i get an "Invalid Argument" javascript error when i click one of the link buttons.. ?

Comment: thank you =] i very much appreciate it!  normally i can look at something and figure it out as i go... but i've been running into a brick wall on this for the last 4 hours...

Answer (score 0):

To actually move the elements on the page you need to remove them from the document and reinsert them in the desired order. First off the line

```
if (item == id) {
```

will not work as you expect as item is a DOM element and to compare it to an id you would need to do :

```
if(item.id == id){
```

Now specifically to your question when counter == 0 item[counter-1] will be out of the bounds of the array and does not exist.

Comment: this is a good point.  and i will test/fix the if statement.  thank you :-)  -  -  - but how do i remove the elements from the document and re insert them?

Comment: A good basic article on Dom Manipulation is here: http://www.dustindiaz.com/add-remove-elements-reprise/. For your specific case you could use items[count].parentNode.removeChild(items[count]) and as patrick posted using: items[count].parentNode.insertBefore(items[count],prev);